# Is this SQLDependency's normal behavior?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
 void  OnDependencyChange(object sender,SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("changed");

   }
```

I'm running a query in ViewModel, I get the result (Let's say 10). If I try to insert instantly to SQL a new row, I don't the `MessageBox`. However, If I stop debugging and re-run my application, It will show as If the value changed which it did. Isn't SQLDependency supposed to give you real time notifications?

I was expecting the MessageBox to show the minute I add a new row in my table.

Comment: what if you don't debug and run the application

Comment: Like from the .exe?

Comment: I mean, don't put a breakpoint and run the application or run on release mode

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual question is here. Have you looked at the documentation and tried basic tests in a test application, with a minimal verifiable test

Comment: @Rahul I still receive the MessageBox yes, but I don't understand what I keep receiving it each time I run the application? even If the value only changes onces?

Comment: @TheGeneral that's actaully what I'm doing, from what I read, It should push a notification automatically but that's not happening here. Do I need a timer?